# Generate the steps for a given string by traversing a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

You have the following grid.

> ```
> A B C D
> E F G H
> I J K L
> M N O P
> Q R S T
> U V W X
> Y Z
> ```

You cursor starts at A always and you have the operation Left (L), Right (R), Up (U), Down (D) and Enter (E). 
QUESTION: Given a string, print the sequence of operation to generate the string?

For example :

```
> INPUT : CGH 
> OUTPUT : R R E D E R E
```

This question was asked to me in the interview.

`My approach` : I thought to solve this by calculating the manhattan distance and do a BFS on the graph, but i think so it is not optimal. and even i need to change the manhattan distance for every letter.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read this again, I have made the necessary changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naive approach one can start from. Hint: look at the initial sequence as a matrix, every letter has a position: row and column indeces.

#### Step 1.

Build a hashtable: *key* - is letter, *value* - is indeces in the 2d matrix. You would use this for fast lookup, for example given letter 'C' what is its matrix indeces? It is [0,2].

Building takes O(N) time and O(N) space as you need to iterate over the input and store it. Resolving a letter takes O(1) in average case + if you use a good hash function the worst case of O(N) wouldn't be a problem.

#### Step 2.

Given 2 letters from the input resolve the offset. This will  give you the desired chunk of the output sequence.

This takes O(1) time and O(1) space.

#### Step 3.

Repeat step 2 until you reach the end of sequence.

This takes O(N) time and O(N) space that is used for building the output.

#### Summary.

This solution uses hashtable for fast letter look up. Offset for resolving the paths (L/R/U/D/E) It also takes O(N) time complexity and O(N) space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the position of the letter in the grid is easy to compute:

```
function get_pos( c : char)
begin
  int col ← (c-'A') modulo 4
  int row ← (c-'A') div 4
  return (row,col)
end
```

#### Assuming positions (6,2) and (6,3) can be used

We can simply define a subtraction between cell coordinates as:

```
function subtract( pos1, pos2 : position )
begin
  return (pos2.row-pos1.row, pos2.col-pos1.col)
end
```

If the subtraction yields a pair (x,y) then the path is simply x times the chararacter 'R' if x is positive or 'L' if x is negative possibliy nothing if x is zero, and similarly y times the character 'D' if y is positive or 'U' if y is negative possibly nothing if y is zero, then we end with the character 'E'.

```
function print_row_path( pos1, pos2 : position )
begin
  path ← subtract(pos1,pos2)
  if path.row > 0 then
    print_times_char(path.row,'R')
  else if path.row < 0
    print_times_char(-path.row,'L')
  end if
end


function print_col_path( pos1, pos2 : position )
begin
  path ← subtract(pos1,pos2)
  if path.col > 0 then
    print_times_char(path.col,'D')
  else if path.col < 0
    print_times_char(-path.col,'U')
  end if
end

function print_path_direction( pos1, pos2 : position ; first_direction : direction )
begin
  if (first_direction = FIRST_MOVE_ROW) then
    print_row_path(pos1,pos2)
    print_col_path(pos1,pos2)
  else
    print_col_path(pos1,pos2)
    print_row_path(pos1,pos2)
  end if
  print 'E'
end

function print_path(start, end : char)
begin
  position pos1 ← get_pos(start)
  position pos2 ← get_pos(end)
  print_path_direction(pos1,pos2, FIRST_MOVE_ROW)
end
```

Where print_times_char(t,c) is a function which prints t times the character c. I defined two "flavours" of path printing, one printing the row movements first and another printing column movements first.

#### Assuming positions (6,2) and (6,3) are forbiden

If we're not allowed to use positions (6,2) and (6,3) then:

- if 'A' ≤ start,end ≤ 'X' or 'Y' ≤ start,end ≤ 'Z' : (6,2) or (6.3) will never be used in the path
- if 'A' ≤ start ≤ 'X' and 'Y' ≤ end ≤ 'Z' : to ensure to not use forbidden cells print columns movements first
- if 'A' ≤ end ≤ 'X' and 'Y' ≤ start ≤ 'Z' : this time we have to print row movements first

In pseudo code:

```
function print_path_wo_forbidden(start, end : char)
begin
  position pos1 ← get_pos(start)
  position pos2 ← get_pos(end)
  if if 'A' ≤ start ≤ 'X' and 'Y' ≤ end ≤ 'Z' then
    print_path_direction(pos1,pos2, FIRST_MOVE_COLUMN)
  else
    print_path_direction(pos1,pos2, FIRST_MOVE_COLUMN)
  end if
end
```

#### Complexity

Printing the path between two positions is clearly in O(1), so for a string of length n we can build an O(n) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the letters are pairs of coordinates `A = [0,0], F = [1,1]`, etc, then you just calculate the offset between the current letter and the desired letter and use that.

Answer (score 0):

What oleski said, but honestly, a hashtable is too much needless programming work, especially if your language doesn't have a native one.

It's often much easier to use an array to map your grid locations like so:

```
struct point{
   int x; 
   int y;
};

point map[256];
point['C'] = (0,2);
```